# Create markup by Template literal not working in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I am using template literals to create marup : but it's showing string format.
But we can use template literals in Html, please help me.

here is the code

```
cmp.set('v.colData', `<th aria-label="Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable slds-text-title_caps" scope="col">Name</th>`);
```

[image: Here is the image, But we can use template literals in html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework turns all HTML found in the `.cmp` file on the server-side into Lightning Components that are rendered into the DOM on the client-side. There is no equivalent automatic conversion of HTML fragments contained in JavaScript, and AFAIK no API to do that.

You can output HTML using the [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml) component and you could dynamically create that component in JavaScript. But components such as [lightning:dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable) do not at present allow you to inject other components into cells.

Best to stick to the patterns that are documented and that have examples: the framework is [opinionated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802050/what-is-opinionated-software).